# Using MySQL for a local database

Tags: mysql, offline

I have written a program for a client that manages orders for his photography/souvenir business. However, I am trying to implement a DBMS for him so that he can do some analysis of the relevant trends over time.

The client's machine is a standalone Windows 8 PC.

I am attempting to use MySQL as he doesn't wish to purchase MS Access. However, he only wants it to be stored locally on the same machine he takes the orders on. How would I go about setting this up? I am new to database management so some detail would be really helpful!

Comment: Can you provide more detail, as to what type of system it would be installed on?

Comment: It would help to indicate witch operation system you are using. If it is windows you can install WAMP http://www.wampserver.com/en/

Comment: It's being installed on a standalone Windows 8 PC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow [MySQL's](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/windows-installation.html) documentation to install. They have a [GUI](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-installer-gui.html).

Once installed make sure to add a strong root password.

I would also create a database `MyAwesomeNewDatabase` specifically for your data. Then create a user for your application to use that is limited to just the database.

`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON MyAwesomeNewDatabase.* To 'user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';`

Then your application can use 'user' and 'password' to communicate. Specifying `localhost` means 'user' can only log in if on that machine, which you indicated is the case.

You indicated VB.net. You will need to install [mysql-connector-net](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/)

Then in Visual Studio add reference to the dlls. [Codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/493133/Connecting-to-MySQL-databases-using-VB-NET) has a good tutorial on this.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it's not installing MySQL that's the issue, its whether or not it can be used locally and if so how?

Comment: Awesome! Thanks, this has answered pretty much all of my questions

Answer (score 0):

You can always use DB at local computer. All you need to do is change the DB config done in your project. Change the address to localhost. I may be able to help more if i get the language you're working upon and the part of code where DB credentials are defined.

Comment: I'm using VB and not too sure how to deal with DB credentials, didn't actually think that was an issue since it's on a standalone PC with only one user that isn't connected to the internet. In the code I'm pulling together SQL commands based on user input strings (I'm aware this is a vulnerability but since only my client will have access to the computer I don't think its an issue). Sorry, as I said, I'm completely new.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Portable MySQL ,probably this Link help to you:

[Designing Applications for Portability](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/portability.html)

You can always use DB at local computer Normally ...
[sqlite](http://www.sqlite.org/) is better for portable programming!